# QtWebkit custom dns setting without system settings

Tags: qt, dns, qtwebkit

I want to change my dns for every one of my request for some reasons! I work with Qt 5.3 and QtWebkit! I do search but i can not find anything that can help me!
Actually QDnsLookup can't force QtWebkit to set its load() function to use specific look up and it use the system Dns setting at the end!
Any idea?!

Answer (score 1):

Create you own [QNAM](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) subclass and [QWebPage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html) subclass. Implement you DNS resolver there. Then set it for each [QWebPage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html) you create. This way you will get full network control of what happens in WebKit.
To be sure all WebPages will get your [QNAM](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html), subclass [QWebView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebview.html) too and set your QWebPage subclass as page in constructor. Also overload [createWindow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#createWindow) function so all new [QWebView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebview.html) pages(like popups) will be created as your [QWebView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebview.html) subclass.

```
YourWebView::YourWebView(QWidget *parent):QWebView(parent)
{
    this->setPage(new YourWebPageSubclass());
    ...

QWebView * YourWebView::createWindow(QWebPage::WebWindowType type)
{
    YourWebView * view = Q_NULLPTR;    
    switch(type)
    {
    case QWebPage::WebBrowserWindow:
        view = new YourWebView(0);
        break;

    case QWebPage::WebModalDialog:
        view = new YourWebView(0);
        view->setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
        break;
    }
    return view;
}

YourWebPageSubclass::YourWebPageSubclass(QObject *parent):QWebPage(parent)
{
    this->setNetworkAccessManager(new YourQNAM(this));
    ...
```

Comment: Where do you actually implement DNS?

Comment: You need to do this in your QNetworkAccessManager subcalss by overiding  [createRequest](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#createRequest) protected function and manipulating [QNetworkRequest parameter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html) exchanging host adress with your own

Comment: can your write simple one for me or any link or site please?